# How to configure side by side 2 versions of WCF on single IIS instance

Tags: wcf, iis

I have several websites on a IIS server (on different ports), some of them uses .NET 4.0 some uses .NET 3.5 - all of them needs WCF.

It is possible to register both (3.5 & 4.0) WCF versions on single IIS ?

I've tried to register WCF in IIS using:

```
ServiceModelReg.exe -ia (from .NET 4.0)
```

and

```
ServiceModelReg.exe -i (from .NET 3.0)
```

When I've installed WCF components with the last command it breaks sites running .NET 4.0, after:

```
ServiceModelReg.exe -u (from .NET 3.0)
ServiceModelReg.exe -ia (from .NET 4.0)
ServiceModelReg.exe -r (from .NET 4.0)
```

they work ok but now the sites using .NET 3.5 break.

Comment: Having 2 different virtual directories running under diff app pools should work. Make sure you have both 3.5 and 4.0 frameworks installed and registered with IIS

Comment: IIS7 - both .NET versions installed & registered, not only separate virtual directories but also websites. Have been working on previous server - now after migration sth is messed up :(

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure you have registered all ASP.NET runtimes against IIS using `aspnet_regiis.exe`
- Make sure each running it in its dedicated application pool
- Set the .NET version for the application pool in the IIS manager console

Comment: - Pool A - Works in .NET 4.0
- Pool B - Works in .NET 2.0
- WebSite X - in Pool A
- WebSite Y - in Pool B
- Reinstalled both ASP.NET using aspnet_regiis.exe -ir -enable from .NET v.2.0 & v.4.0
- Before I've posted question I have to remove .NET v2.0 WCF using ServiceModelReg.exe -u
- WebSite X - works OK
- WebSite Y - HTTP 500: The configuration section 'system.serviceModel' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
 1. aspnet_regiis.exe -i -enable (from v2.0...)
 2. ServiceModelReg.exe -i (from v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation)
 3. aspnet_regiis.exe -i -enable (from v4.0...)
 4. ServiceModelReg.exe -ia (from v4.0...)
 5. iisreset
```

Don't really sure what was changed, maybe the order of execution was important.